# Identifying fleas in my garden

Tags: identification, insects

Just bought a new house and the garden is filled with some kind of flea-like insect. You can't notice them normally but put anything white on the grass and they jump on it instantly.

[Here is a video](https://photos.app.goo.gl/lkgWz2wnyvgWxVjS2)

And some photos:

[image: a]
[image: b]
[image: c]
[image: d]

They're maybe 1mm long and they jump like fleas. The previous owners apparently had two cats, and there are definitely cats still roaming. But they're not in the house at all and they don't bite us.

Anyone have any ideas or know a better place to ask?

Comment: They're not fleas nor ticks, because this insect has wings. Looks like some type of fly, just not sure which, but it reminds me of a sand fly- they're small, jump and land on anything pale coloured, like yellow or white. Where are you in the world?

Comment: These look more like flies than fleas. What you perceive as flea-like behavior is more likely than not mating rituals. Doubt they harm anything significantly.

Comment: I'm in England. Hmm interesting. I forgot to mention that these things can't fly at all. Are there species of fly that don't fly?

Comment: You're not near the coast are you? Sand flies have wings, but jump, so they can do both, you just don't necessarily see them flying. Are you near any stables?

Comment: In Bristol, so not particularly near the coast and not near any stables that I know of.

Comment: Is your soil/lawn waterlogged? Has there been any manure or composted materials spread about lately? Do you have stagnant water or leaking drains anywhere?

Comment: Don't think so! Although this is Bristol so it's not exactly dry!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try a leafhopper, Aphrodes bifasciatus. Seems to fit the pictures and the descriptive behaviour. It is a jumping bug not a fly but many insects have wings.

Comment: Aphrodes trifasciatus is more like it...https://www.britishbugs.org.uk/homoptera/Cicadellidae/Aphrodes_trifasciatus.html